# couchdb - deleting revision

Tags: nosql, couchdb

How is it possible to relete old revisions of couchdb document?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot delete an old revision of a *single* document. This is because the old revisions are only used by CouchDB internally for concurrency control and you shouldn't have to worry about these revisions.

If you want to remove *all* old revisions in order to shrink the size of your database, you can run [compaction](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/maintenance/compaction.html).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Revisions of single document can be deleted by identifying the revision id. Example:
```curl -X DELETE $HOST/db-replica/foo?rev=2-de0ea16f8621cbac506d23a0fbbde08a```

See this document on Couch conflict resolution for more detail:
https://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html

Answer (score 2):

take care that it is not enough to delete the documents and their revisions with compaction, still some data is being saved in the db such as the last revision of the document.

In order to be 100% sure to delete all data you have to purge your db using this api:

**POST /{db}/_purge**

More on: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/misc.html